# Rings are $\mathsf{Ab}$-categories with one object. What are commutative rings?

Tags: category-theory

Is there a nice and simple definition of commutative rings that does not use the notion of a commutative monoid object?

How, in general, can one "externally" capture the commutative of a set operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commutative rings are monoidal $\mathsf{Ab}$-categories with one object. (Yes, symmetric monoidal is not assumed; it follows.)

Answer (score 3):

Commutativity has to do with how much a monoid object can be [delooped](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping). In general, there are infinitely many levels of delooping corresponding to infinitely many levels of commutativity, and monoids which can be delooped $n$ times are called $E_n$ algebras. One way of saying what this means is that an $E_n$ algebra in a (symmetric monoidal, or $E_{\infty}$) category $C$ is

- an $n$-category
- where the $n$-morphisms are enriched over $C$ but everything else is as usual
- with one object, one $1$-morphism, one $2$-morphism, etc.

It sometimes happens that $E_n$ automatically implies $E_{\infty}$. If $C$ is an ordinary symmetric monoidal category, such as $\text{Set}$ or $\text{Vect}$, then $E_2$ automatically implies $E_{\infty}$. But this can fail if $C$ is an interesting higher category.

Comment: Interesting. Where does one learn this? Is this homotopy theory, perhaps?

Comment: @goblin: certainly homotopy theory was the first place where these sorts of issues were first recognized (in May's *Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces*), but these issues occur in other domains where higher category is used now, e.g. in Lurie's approach to derived algebraic geometry.